# What is the correct way to rename an uploaded file using tokens?

Tags: webforms, tokens

I am building a webform. I have a *Name* field that uses first and last name.
I have an image upload field where I want to rename the image to *lastname-firstname.jpg*.

In the properties for the file upload, I selected *Rename files* for the pattern *[webform:element:name:last__title]-[webform:element:name:first__title]*.

When I test this using John Smith, the file is getting renamed, but it is being renamed to *last-name-first-name.png* instead of *smith-john.jpg*.

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the pattern, but I don't know what.

This is the field definition.

```yaml
name:
  '#type': name
  '#title': Name
  '#title__access': false
  '#first__title': 'First Name'
  '#middle__access': false
  '#last__title': 'Last Name'
  '#suffix__access': false
  '#degree__access': false
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The answer was buried way down in *Browse available tokens*.

I wanted to rename an uploaded file based on the responses to the *last_name* and *first_name* fields. The pattern that worked was *[webform_submission:values:last_name]_[webform_submission:values:first_name]*.